# ocquickview.js not work normally

Tags: opencart

ocquickview.js not normally works on OpenCart.

The console response is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (ocquickview.js:30)
>       at Function.each (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
>       at n.fn.init.each (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
>       at Object.initQuickViewButton (ocquickview.js:21)
>       at ocquickview.js:14
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at HTMLDocument. (ocquickview.js:13)
>       at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)
>       at Object.trigger (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)`
>
> And this is the crashed line
>
> `if(url.search('route=product/product') != -1

Does anybody have a mind about this?

Thank in Advance!

Comment: check if that img tag has href value or not?

Comment: @Radhika thank you for answer the matter has solved but the zooming not work yet now console response is :                               (unknown) XHR Loaded (index.php - 200 OK - 56.82147900556447ms - 740B)
(unknown) XHR Loaded (client.az.min.json - 200 OK - 14.758729975670576ms - 382B)
(unknown) XHR Loaded (300lo.json - 200 OK - 288.4484980357229ms - 867B)
(unknown) XHR Loaded (shares.json - 200 OK - 446.155363954138ms - 524B)
(unknown) XHR Loaded (index.php - 200 OK - 70.82147503027227ms - 1.329KB) Can you help this ?

Comment: Which Zoom js are you using?

Comment: Thank you @Radhika i already have been solved the problem so the main problem for not working was using mistaked sizes so my image content's data-zoom-image size 500*500 px and src value was 1000*1000 i only changed their value each other .So the matter was solved .